# phpmyadmin login is not working i an entering username and password but its still same page without any error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, rds

```
    <?php
    /*
     * Generated configuration file
     * Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.2.11 setup script
     * Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2015 09:49:00 +0200
     */

    /* Servers configuration */
    $i = 0;

    /* Server: dsfd [1] */
    $i++;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xyzkfjaklfk.s.rds.amazonaws.com';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ' ';


    /* End of servers configuration */

    $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '231464654654';
    $cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
    $cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;`enter code here`
    $cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
    $cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
    ?>
```

if i am using `'auth_type' = 'cookie';` its not login show same login page with error.but i am using `auth_type= 'http';` login but show `token mismatch` error.
Help me to resolve error.

Comment: what OS is the one with phpmyadmin ?

Comment: try this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04